# coreapi only lists list and read method, even when user is logged

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, core-api

I'm building a Django Rest Framework and want to test the `API` with `coreapi` library. I can create an object using `coreapi` programmatically inside a python script but in command line, I can't create the same object and when I list `coreapi` endpoints I get a list with only endpoints for reading and listing, even when I add a valid credential.

**My Schema:**

```
{
    "_type": "document",
    "_meta": {
        "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/schema/",
        "title": "NEP API"
    },
    "experiments": {

        "list": {
            "_type": "link",
            "url": "/api/experiments/",
            "action": "get",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "name": "page",
                    "location": "query",
                    "schema": {
                        "_type": "integer",
                        "title": "Page",
                        "description": "A page number within the paginated result set."
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "create": {
            "_type": "link",
            "url": "/api/experiments/",
            "action": "post",
            "encoding": "application/json",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "name": "title",
                    "required": true,
                    "location": "form",
                    "schema": {
                        "_type": "string",
                        "title": "Title",
                        "description": ""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "description",
                    "required": true,
                    "location": "form",
                    "schema": {
                        "_type": "string",
                        "title": "Description",
                        "description": ""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "data_acquisition_done",
                    "location": "form",
                    "schema": {
                        "_type": "boolean",
                        "title": "Data acquisition done",
                        "description": ""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "nes_id",
                    "required": true,
                    "location": "form",
                    "schema": {
                        "_type": "integer",
                        "title": "Nes id",
                        "description": ""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "ethics_committee_file",
                    "location": "form",
                    "schema": {
                        "_type": "string",
                        "title": "Project file approved by the ethics committee",
                        "description": ""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "sent_date",
                    "required": true,
                    "location": "form",
                    "schema": {
                        "_type": "string",
                        "title": "Sent date",
                        "description": ""
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "read": {
            "_type": "link",
            "url": "/api/experiments/{nes_id}/",
            "action": "get",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "name": "nes_id",
                    "required": true,
                    "location": "path",
                    "schema": {
                        "_type": "string",
                        "title": "",
                        "description": ""
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "update": {
            "_type": "link",
            "url": "/api/experiments/{nes_id}/",
            "action": "put",
            "encoding": "application/json",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "name": "nes_id",
                    "required": true,
                    "location": "path",
                    "schema": {
                        "_type": "string",
                        "title": "",
                        "description": ""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "title",
                    "required": true,
                    "location": "form",
                    "schema": {
                        "_type": "string",
                        "title": "Title",
                        "description": ""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "description",
                    "required": true,
                    "location": "form",
                    "schema": {
                        "_type": "string",
                        "title": "Description",
                        "description": ""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "data_acquisition_done",
                    "location": "form",
                    "schema": {
                        "_type": "boolean",
                        "title": "Data acquisition done",
                        "description": ""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "nes_id",
                    "required": true,
                    "location": "form",
                    "schema": {
                        "_type": "integer",
                        "title": "Nes id",
                        "description": ""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "ethics_committee_file",
                    "location": "form",
                    "schema": {
                        "_type": "string",
                        "title": "Project file approved by the ethics committee",
                        "description": ""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "sent_date",
                    "required": true,
                    "location": "form",
                    "schema": {
                        "_type": "string",
                        "title": "Sent date",
                        "description": ""
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "partial_update": {
            "_type": "link",
            "url": "/api/experiments/{nes_id}/",
            "action": "patch",
            "encoding": "application/json",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "name": "nes_id",
                    "required": true,
                    "location": "path",
                    "schema": {
                        "_type": "string",
                        "title": "",
                        "description": ""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "title",
                    "location": "form",
                    "schema": {
                        "_type": "string",
                        "title": "Title",
                        "description": ""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "description",
                    "location": "form",
                    "schema": {
                        "_type": "string",
                        "title": "Description",
                        "description": ""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "data_acquisition_done",
                    "location": "form",
                    "schema": {
                        "_type": "boolean",
                        "title": "Data acquisition done",
                        "description": ""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "nes_id",
                    "location": "form",
                    "schema": {
                        "_type": "integer",
                        "title": "Nes id",
                        "description": ""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "ethics_committee_file",
                    "location": "form",
                    "schema": {
                        "_type": "string",
                        "title": "Project file approved by the ethics committee",
                        "description": ""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "sent_date",
                    "location": "form",
                    "schema": {
                        "_type": "string",
                        "title": "Sent date",
                        "description": ""
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "delete": {
            "_type": "link",
            "url": "/api/experiments/{nes_id}/",
            "action": "delete",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "name": "nes_id",
                    "required": true,
                    "location": "path",
                    "schema": {
                        "_type": "string",
                        "title": "",
                        "description": ""
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
}
```

As you see, all methods are listed here and I cant create an `experiment` object by using `coreapi` programmatically inside a script, for example, running (inside a python script):

```
client.action(
        schema, ['experiments', 'create'],
        params={'title': 'An experimet', 'description': 'A description',
                'nes_id': 2, 'sent_date': '2017-01-01'}
    )
```

But when using `coreapi` in command line I can't create same object.

**Getting schema:**

```
$ coreapi get http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/schema
```

display the and points when not logged:

```
<NEP API "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/schema/">
    experiments: {
        groups: {
            list(experiment_nes_id, [page])
        }
        studies: {
            list(experiment_nes_id, [page])
        }
        list([page])
        read(nes_id)
    }
    groups: {
        list([page])
    }
    protocol_components: {
        list([page])
        read(nes_id)
    }
    studies: {
        list([page])
    }
```

Then, I add my credentials:

```
$ coreapi credentials add 127.0.0.1 "lab1":"nep-lab1" --auth basic
```

Reload the schema:

```
$ coreapi reload
```

and the result is again

```
<NEP API "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/schema/">
    experiments: {
        groups: {
            list(experiment_nes_id, [page])
        }
        studies: {
            list(experiment_nes_id, [page])
        }
        list([page])
        read(nes_id)
    }
    groups: {
        list([page])
    }
    protocol_components: {
        list([page])
        read(nes_id)
    }
    studies: {
        list([page])
    }
```

Now, I expect that the endpoints would appear including create, update etc. but no.

And when I try to create an `experiment` object running:

```
$ coreapi action experiments create --param nes_id=5 --param title="A" --param description="B" --param sent_date="2001-01-01"
```

I get, as expected:

```
Index ['experiments']['create'] did not reference a link. Key 'create' was not found.
```

**url conf:**

I am using Default Router to generate REST uri's:

```
router.register(r'experiments', api.ExperimentViewSet,
                base_name='api_experiments')
router = DefaultRouter()
```

and including in url conf:

```
url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
```

Sorry by the long text. I wanted to include as much as information I thought was necessary.

Answer (score 11):

Had the same issue when working on tutorial (part 7) at official Django Rest Framework site.

Found one solution:
**manually add header Authorization to requests** using `coreapi headers add HEADER VALUE`, where `VALUE` is the string of characters, which is generated when you add credentials of user. For some reason my *coreapi* didn't add this header automatically to request as I found with `--debug` option.

Here is example:

Before credentials are added I can see only safe methods:

```
$ coreapi get http://127.0.0.1:8000/schema/
<Pastebin API "http://127.0.0.1:8000/schema/">
    snippets: {
        list([page])
        read(id)
        highlight(id)
    }
    users: {
        list([page])
        read(id)
    }
```

Then I add credentials of superuser *admin*:

```
coreapi credentials add 127.0.0.1 "admin:password" --auth basic
Added credentials
127.0.0.1 "Basic BlahBlahBlah="
```

It looks like coreapi successfully add credentials, but when I try to reload schema, I still get the same methods:

```
$ coreapi reload
<Pastebin API "http://127.0.0.1:8000/schema/">
    snippets: {
        list([page])
        read(id)
        highlight(id)
    }
    users: {
        list([page])
        read(id)
    }
```

I found that there is no `Authorization` header in GET request with value `Basic BlahBlahBlah=`:

```
$ coreapi reload --debug
> GET /schema/ HTTP/1.1
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
> Connection: keep-alive
> Accept: application/coreapi+json, application/vnd.coreapi+json, */*
> Host: 127.0.0.1
> User-Agent: coreapi
```

Well, let's try to add this header to our request manually:

```
$ coreapi headers add "Authorization" "Basic BlahBlahBlah="
Added header
Authorization: Basic BlahBlahBlah=
```

Try again to get schema:

```
$ coreapi get http://127.0.0.1:8000/schema/
<Pastebin API "http://127.0.0.1:8000/schema/">
    snippets: {
        list([page])
        create(code, [title], [linenos], [language], [style])
        read(id)
        update(id, code, [title], [linenos], [language], [style])
        partial_update(id, [title], [code], [linenos], [language], [style])
        delete(id)
        highlight(id)
    }
    users: {
        list([page])
        read(id)
    }
```

Now I see all other methods available to authorized users only. If I execute previous command with `--debug` option, there will be the header:

```
> GET /schema/ HTTP/1.1
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
> Connection: keep-alive
> Accept: application/coreapi+json, application/vnd.coreapi+json, */*
> Authorization: Basic BlahBlahBlah=
> Host: 127.0.0.1
> User-Agent: coreapi
```

For example, now I can create code snippet:

```
$ coreapi action snippets create --param title="Example" --param code="print('hello, world')"
{
    "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippets/6/",
    "id": 6,
    "highlight": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippets/6/highlight/",
    "owner": "admin",
    "title": "Example",
    "code": "print('hello, world')",
    "linenos": false,
    "language": "python",
    "style": "friendly"
}
```

But still there is the question *Why doesn't coreapi add Authorization header automatically?*

Comment: Thank you for this. I followed the same tuto and have the same issue. It didn't solve it all for me but it's a good step. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I found the exact same issue on Django Rest Framework tutorial, so it is still an issue with these versions:

```
$ pip list
...
coreapi (2.3.3)
coreapi-cli (1.0.6)
...
```

The issue documented here: https://github.com/core-api/coreapi-cli/issues/19.  Relevant excerpt:

> coreapi-cli is using the deprecated credentials argument for HTTPTransport instead of auth. As you can see from the code here, coreapi 2.3.1 is ingesting that deprecated argument, but then doing nothing with it. This is why this library won't send auth headers anymore.

I can confirm that adding the header fixed it for me.  In summary:

```
coreapi clear
coreapi credentials add 127.0.0.1 admin:password --auth basic
coreapi credentials show
coreapi headers add "Authorization" "Basic ...=="
coreapi get http://127.0.0.1:8000/schema/ --debug
```

Copy-paste the string from "credentials show" command into "headers add" command.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug with version 2.3.x. of coreapi-cli. A fix is coming soon, see:

[Issue tracked on Github](https://github.com/core-api/coreapi-cli/issues/19)

The work around is as per Sergey Dulevich's previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to mention that i do not see these issue's when using the python client directly (when providing Basic Auth credentials).

```
from coreapi import Client

client = Client(auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))
document = client.get(args.endpoint)
data = client.action(document, ['catalog', 'create', ], params={
        'start': '2018-08-30T10:00:00Z',
        'end': '2018-08-30T11:00:00Z',
        'filename': 'my-filename',
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

This also happened to me after authenticating on basic-auth with:

```
$ coreapi credentials add 127.0.0.1 <user>:'<pass>' --auth basic
```

Now you will find the REST un-SAFE methods are listed, using: `coreapi action snippets list` - check for those methods:

> ```
>     list([page])
>     create(code, [title], [linenos], [language], [style])
>     read(id)
>     update(id, code, [title], [linenos], [language], [style])
>     partial_update(id, [title], [code], [linenos], [language], [style])
>     delete(id)
>     read_0(id, format)
>     read_1(id, format)
>     update_0(id, format, code, [title], [linenos], [language], [style])
>     partial_update_0(id, format, [title], [code], [linenos], [language], [style])
>     delete_0(id, format)
> ```

Then if I tried to create a resource such as:

```
$ coreapi action snippets create --param title="Example" --param code="print('hello, world from the CLI')"
```

it would fail with `"Index ['snippets']['create'] did not reference a link. Key 'create' was not found."`

I was able to **solve** it by reading again the schema after the auth step:

```
$ coreapi get http://127.0.0.1:8008/schema/
```

This must act like a refresh of the schema and it then allows to create the resource using the exact same code from above.

Try it and see if it works for you as well.